# What is negative pressure?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, pressure

Is pressure below vacuum which is zero possible? If yes, please explain how because I can't think how is that possible because in vacuum there are no molecules and how can we achieve something below that?

Comment: Tip: Check the right margin for duplicates.

Comment: Welcome to SE Physics. Your question has already been asked and has a good answer here;  https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/173961/ . If you have additional questions  you could ask by giving more details about what are you looking for.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Negative pressure](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/173961/)

Comment: I tried understanding it but still can't wrap my mind around how can this be possible